# Matching query does not exist using Postman

Tags: python-3.x

It says for my error Meal matching query does not exist, I can't seem to find a problem where it says there is a error in my terminal (apis.py line 66). I will post a picture of my code from apis and a picture of the error. Does anyone know what i am doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by changing the meal id I was searching for. At some point I deleted the meal with id = 1, so when I queried for ID 1 it was telling me there was no meal to be found. Make sure your querying for data that is ACTUALLY in your database. Django does not automatically reorder your id when you delete another (unless you tell it to), in my case I had not - causing the unmatched query.